# You have 6 burning candles

Tags: mathematics, science

What's the answer for this question:

You have 6 burning candles, and blow out two of them. How many candles are left standing after 24 hours? How do you know?

Comment: Depends on what kind of candles, whether they stand at all, whether it's raining, and what other random things you were thinking of when posting this

Comment: Look like a "trick joke" to me, like : "A plane with 425 passengers and 10 crew members crashed on the border between USA and Canada. 300 dead. Where are the survivors buried?". No need to assume anything, you burn 6 candles, blow out 2, 2 are standing after 24 hours because 4 melted. (this kind of joke is more effective orally)

Answer (score 2):

Assumption:

> If weather is clear, the candles are of normal size and all in standing position

then answer is:

> 2 as others will burn out

Comment: It is asking for the number of candles *standing*

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume conditions are perfect, and that the wax on the candles lasts more than twenty-four hours.

The question asks for the number of candles standing, so:

> All six will be *standing*, but two will be blown out (but the amount blown out is beside the point).

Comment: I think you misunderstood it or do you think I? the candles are burning in start and blow out means stop burning and its asking about 24 hrs not 2 hours

Comment: @Preet I've edited the answer to 24 hours. I think that I have the correct answer because the question as stated says "standing", and you could blow out all six candles and all six would still be standing.